How to use the same package name for another crate in crates.io?
I want to take over the no longer maintained open source Rust package that is already deployed in crates.io.
While it is obviously in place and appropriate to require a different name for my fork in Cargo.toml, I would prefer not to require changes in the rest of the code, to make switching easier for potential users. When I simply renamed the entry in Cargo.toml, lots of code got broken everywhere. Exactly the old name is required.
It looks more logical to provide pluggable implementations of the same functionality the user can easily switch between, comparing performance and results of the own tests.
As a workaround, I am currently specifying the git URL in Cargo.toml:
old_name = { git = "https://github.com/new_repository", branch = "1.0.0" }

This works for me when testing my own deployment. But I probably should prefer crates.io for a public open-source project.
Is it possible to deploy a project on crates.io under a different name than the package name as referenced in the code, and how? I checked the documentation of cargo publish, but it does not seem to cover this case.
EDIT: If it is not possible to achieve this without refactoring, please give hints how to refactor the code that it would not require mass renaming every time the name of the package changes. Most of the references to the own package name seem to be in the tests.

What is for you here wrong? The project is explicitly marked as "deprecated" and repository is set read only (archived), would it still be unethical to continue it? I do not want to ask the author go give me access to the original name because who I am starting from, and then I may not be the only person who wants to take over. The question is strictly about the cargo publish tool and maybe some work arounds.

You cannot do that automatically, and that's a good thing. I do not want crates to have hidden names in source code, for good or bad reasons. If you want to do this, your users will have to be explicit about this.

I still think the project at least should be able to reference the own subpackages without depending where, how an by whom it is depolyed.

Subpackages, yes, and that's a request for publishable workspace dependencies, which was already asked many times and will probably be implemented one day too. Tests/examples, maybe, but this is not implemented AFAIK, and honestly the change is not too disturbing with few search/replace. Dependents of your crates, no, as I've explained.

Most of the references to the own project name are in the tests. I am missing some keyword that would resolve to the own project name there. I tried crate:: and this:: but seems not working as expected. If already to refactor the project, better so that others would not need the same mass renaming after me.

Integration tests, doctests or unit tests?

Unit tests of the project. These are in the folder called "tests" sitting next to the "src", "target" and "Cargo.toml". Are they at the wrong place? If you have an idea how to refactor, let me known.

In tests/ there are integration tests. Unit tests are #[test]s inside src/.

Still need to do something with them.

Unit tests can just use crate::, it's only the integration tests that need to refer to the package name as if they were external code. Maybe some (or all?) of your integration tests should actually be unit tests.

A dependent crate can rename a dependency by specifying the package (documentation). Here's how that'd look:
old_name = { package = "new_name", version = "..." }

This means that it will be accessible as old_name in the code, but cargo will look for it as new_name when resolving.
There is no way to publish as one name but have users use it with a different name besides this.


Most of the references to the [old] package name seem to be in the tests.

For renaming within the crate itself (for integration tests, examples, etc), you can avoid a complete refactor by using an alias in each scope it is used:
use ::new_name as old_name;

